# Python Error "TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument 'attachmentId'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I am trying to pull an attachment from an email from gmail using their API and have run into an unexpected keyword argument when trying to plug in a variable. I am very used to Javascript so that is probably why I am running into this error and getting it wrong but here is the relevant block of code:

```
def main():

    credentials = get_credentials()
    gsa = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    query = ['plc/trending/31day']

    for x in query:

        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=None, q='label:' + x, pageToken=None, maxResults=1, includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
        mesgid = results['messages'][0]['id']
        attresults = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=mesgid, format=None, metadataHeaders=None).execute()
        attid = attresults['payload']['parts'][1]['body']['attachmentId']
        grabattachment = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId='me', messageId = mesgid, attachmentId = attid)
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of a `attachmentId` argument to that method in the [official API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get), no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) states that the id of an attachment is named `id`, not `attachmentId`:

```
grabattachment = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId='me', messageId = mesgid, id = attid)
```

You probably want to cache the `service.users().messages()` and deeper calls like `.attachments()` and avoid having to call so many objects each time:

```
messages = service.users().messages()
for x in query:
    results = messages.list(
        userId='me', labelIds=None, q='label:' + x, 
        pageToken=None, maxResults=1, 
        includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
    mesgid = results['messages'][0]['id']
    attresults = messages.get(
        userId='me', id=mesgid, format=None, 
        metadataHeaders=None).execute()
    attid = attresults['payload']['parts'][1]['body']['attachmentId']
    grabattachment = messages.attachments().get(
        userId='me', messageId=mesgid,
        attachmentId=attid)
```

I also strongly suspect that you are missing the `.execute()` call at the end.

I also have the impression taht the `messages.list()` call already contains enough information to retrieve the attachment without requiring a separate `messages.get()` call:

```
messages = service.users().messages()
for x in query:
    results = messages.list(
        userId='me', labelIds=None, q='label:' + x, 
        pageToken=None, maxResults=1, 
        includeSpamTrash=None).execute()
    attid = results['messages'][0]['payload']['parts'][1]['body']['attachmentId']
    grabattachment = messages.attachments().get(
        userId='me', messageId=mesgid,
        attachmentId=attid).execute()
```

Personally, I would still test for multiple attachments, checking if each has a filename before loading the attachment data.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that myself too, but those tips for making deeper calls helped too! Thanks again!